# Cannot trace error in python pcapy wrapper

Tags: python, networking, docker, pcap, packet-sniffers

I'm using python `pcapy` in a `docker` container using this piece of code:

```
from pcapy import open_live, findalldevs
import sys
import traceback

p = open_live("eth0", 1024, False, 100)
dumper = p.dump_open("test.pcap")

devices = findalldevs()
print dumper, devices
while True:
    try:
        print p.next()
    except Exception as e:
        print dir(e), e.message, e.args[0]
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        break
```

When I run it I get the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test_pcap.py", line 12, in
>
> ```
> print p.next()
> ```
>
> PcapError

I've tried to play with the arguments by changing to different maximum packet sizes and setting promiscuous to `True`.

I've tried to get any message from the exception, but it seems the message is empty. I also skimmed through pcapy [source code](https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pcapy/blob/2984bf5e974ab3a2af58c0501f2d4072db5ac4e4/pcapobj.cc#L197): since the exception in the PcapyError object is empty and the other PcapErrors in the `next` function are explicit strings, it implies we are falling into the condition in which `buf` is empty. It seems `pcap_geterr` returns an empty string because `pp->pcap` has been closed and the pointer to the pcap exception no longer exists (take a look into the [doc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pcap_geterr/)).

When I run using the `loop()` method, everything works fine:

```
# Modified from: http://snipplr.com/view/3579/
import pcapy
from impacket.ImpactDecoder import *

# list all the network devices
pcapy.findalldevs()

max_bytes = 1024
promiscuous = False
read_timeout = 100 # in milliseconds
pc = pcapy.open_live("eth0", max_bytes,
    promiscuous, read_timeout)

# callback for received packets
def recv_pkts(hdr, data):
    packet = EthDecoder().decode(data)
    print packet

packet_limit = -1 # infinite
pc.loop(packet_limit, recv_pkts) # capture packets
```

I really don't know the source of the problem or what else to do for debugging it.

**EDIT**

I cannot find any error using `strace`. This is the grep for error in `strace` output:

```
strace python test_pcap.py 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep -i error
```

> read(6, "\0\0\0t\3\0\0\0intt\n\0\0\0ValueErrort\23\0\0\0_"..., 4096) = 995
>
> getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
>
> getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
>
> getsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0

**EDIT2**

I also tested `pcap.h` by calling to `pcap_next` myself:

```
 // Modified from: http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html
 #include <pcap.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
        pcap_t *handle;                 /* Session handle */
        char *dev;                      /* The device to sniff on */
        char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];  /* Error string */
        bpf_u_int32 mask;               /* Our netmask */
        bpf_u_int32 net;                /* Our IP */
        struct pcap_pkthdr header;      /* The header that pcap gives us */
        const u_char *packet;           /* The actual packet */

        /* Define the device */
        dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
        if (dev == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
                return(2);
        }
        /* Find the properties for the device */
        if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
                net = 0;
                mask = 0;
        }
        /* Open the session in promiscuous mode */
        handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
        if (handle == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", "eth0", errbuf);
                return(2);
        }
        while (1) {
                /* Grab a packet */
                packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
                /* Print its length */
                printf("Jacked a packet with length of [%d]\n", header.len);
                /* Print contents */
                printf("\tPacket: %s\n", packet);
                /* And close the session */
        }
        pcap_close(handle);
        return(0);
 }
```

To compile, write it to `test_sniff.c` and run:

```
gcc test_sniff.c -o test_sniff -lpcap
```

And I was able to capture packets successfully. So I don't really know where the problem is...

**Other info to reproduce behaviour**

- Docker version: `Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef`
- Docker image is the Docker default `Ubuntu`
- Python2.7

Comment: as far as i can see it simply has nothing to do with docker. maybe you use the pcapy api incorrect. what do you want to achive? writing a pcap? why can't you use the second py script?

Comment: I need to process each of the intercepted packets. I pass the output of next (header and payload) to another function that processes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcapy` doesn't use Python `socket` module. It won't raise `socket.timeout` which is raised if timeout has been enabled by previous `socket.settimeout` call. `socket.settimeout` is used to set a `socket` into blocking, non-blocking or timeout state.

In `pcapy`, the timeout argument of `open_live` is passed to `poll` syscall at least in Linux, should differ by OS where `poll` is not available.

`Reader.next` call raises `PcapError` if there's no packet to return because it hasn't captured any packets yet. It's not an error, just an indication like `StopIteration`. It can be ignored and `Reader.next` has to be called again.

`Reader.loop` won't return until it has at least one packet to return or an error occurs.

The following code captures 10 packets and exits.

```
from pcapy import open_live, findalldevs, PcapError

p = open_live("eth0", 1024, False, 100)
dumper = p.dump_open("test.pcap")

devices = findalldevs()
print dumper, devices
count=0
while True:
    try:
        packet = p.next()
    except PcapError:
        continue
    else:
        print packet
        count += 1
        if count == 10:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer is pretty simple:
`p.next()` will `throw` on `timeout`
your timeout is `100ms` (last parameter of `open_live`)

so your `except` should handle the timeout case and you may want to increase the `timeout` time or set it to `0` for `infinite`

edit:
you simply expected `socket.timeout` but `PcapError` is thrown instead. `socket.timeout` is the exception thrown by the socket code in the python lib so it is python specific. It is getting wrapped up (maybe just with new versions of pcapy) or it jsut stands for a different kind of timeout (TCP socket related) 
see example pcapy code: [example](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40a%40packetpig-HEAD%40lib%40scripts%40impacket%40examples%40tracer.py/56/pcapy.PcapError/python)

Comment: That's weird. On other machines, when it times out I catch a `socket.timeout` exception. Why am I getting a `PcapError` instead? In fact, I simplified the code for a minimal example in the question but I am in fact handling socket.timeout in my original code, and the exception is not caught there...

Comment: i don't know why it is acting this way. Maybe it can't open the network device correct in docker. Have you captured a packet with it?

Comment: No, I think you're right on that it doesn't have anything to do with `docker` at all. I tried on a machine different than the host I was using for docker, and I observe the same behavior. I don't know why but I get a `PcapError` in this other machine as well while in the docker host machine I was getting a `socket.timeout` exception.

Comment: Yes, I was running the C code I posted in my question and captured packets successfully.

Comment: +1 because the answer is shedding light to the problem, but I don't consider the issue solved until someone gives an explanation to why `socket.timeout` is not raised...

Comment: I came across this question having the same problem. socket.timeout is thrown for me, not PcapError. To be safe I'm using something similar to the selected answer but also catching socket.timeout.